# What would a truly disgusting human being be?

Tags: ethics, nihilism, love, beauty

What would a truly disgusting human being be? Would it necessarily involve a lack of virtue, and anyway what would its defining features be? What sort of weaknesses would he have?

Comment: probably a bit off topic, and apologies if you just close

Comment: Beauty is in the eye of the beholder. So beauty/ugly is an opinion.

Comment: Someone who doesn't wash their hands after going to the washroom?

Comment: @DKNguyen awooga

Comment: @DKNguyen Right now in Gaza children have [1.5 litres of water](https://www.unicef.org/press-releases/barely-drop-drink-children-gaza-strip-do-not-access-90-cent-their-normal-water-use). Are they disgusting if they dont use toilet paper? Im reminded of Marie Antoinette's cake...

Comment: @Rushi Ahhh, but I'm talking about washing hands, not wiping butts ;)

Comment: Disgust (verb) means: to provoke to loathing, repugnance, or aversion. So sure. E. coli covered children are not disgusting (provoking loathing), or disgusting (provoking repugnance) but they are disgusting (provoking aversion). And if you put them on a boat, and the boat is fast, and you fasten the boat fast fast, the fast fast fast boat that carries the non-disgusting disgusting children will fast be fast and thus no longer fast...

Answer (score 2):

> Question: If (priyam) Love, is a natural attribute, it should be existent no matter what the object may be. Why then is it not existent when we see a tiger or a snake?
>
> Ramana: We ourselves may not have any love for them, but every species has love towards its own kind, hasn’t it? A tiger loves a tiger, and a snake a snake. So also a thief loves a thief and a debauchee a debauchee. Thus, love is always existent.
> — [Letters from Ramana Ashram](https://www.facebook.com/RamanaMaharshi/photos/pb.9944414630.-2207520000.1476751857./10154575919644631/?type=3&paipv=0&eav=AfY-TBNXrUK1fKqlKq78fV2vhLP9YSo7onDa0ltumwRCrYQnt-Fq4mX9jIMXg09v02Y&_rdr)

Answer (score 1):

This is a good question because mixing sentiments with science will never get you closer to the truth.

From God's point of view, there are no good or bad people. There are different people for different jobs (destiny). And similar to wolves vs sheep, wolves (bad people) have a more difficult job to do, and they get more help from God.

Answer (score 0):

I saw a movie on Rifftrax called Galaxy Invader.  And it had a villain that really went far out of his way to be disgusting.  He never changed his clothing, lived in a run-down nasty house, and there was a big tear right in the middle of what was apparently his only shirt.  And every time he had a conflict with his daughter he went chasing her into the woods with his shotgun.  And when his drinking-buddy friend violently died in the woods - instead of showing remorse, he attempted to force himself on the wife who showed up questioning where her husband was, and when she rejected his advances, he shot her.

So to answer your question, while I don't really have an original answer, and my answer might be off topic like your question is, I do think true disgustingness would absolutely necessarily involve a lack of virtue, particularly the virtues of remorse and respect for family relationships, but we can pile bad hygiene on top of that lack of virtue as well, and that makes somebody truly degusting in pretty much every way.